# Livewire lose value of object after render

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to know if there is a kind of order about which object renders first, because I have an array of id keys, and when I load them separately in a var_dump I get both of the value, but when I nest them it gives me an empty string on the uuid.

Component:

```
public $groupId = null, $schedules = [], $lessons = [];

protected $listeners = [
    'getGroups'
];

public function mount()
{
    $this->schedules = [];
    $this->groupId = null;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.scheduler.manager.scheduler');
}

public function getGroups($schedules, $groupId)
{
    $this->groupId = $groupId;
    $this->schedules = $schedules;
}
```

My livewire blade:

```
{{ $schedules[$groupId]['name'] }}
```

When I do a var_dump() on the `$schedules` and on `$groupId` I get the correct data, but when I combine them then the `$groupId` is empty in the blade.

Comment: How are you calling `getGroups` to begin with?

Comment: @Yinci I don't need to call getGroups in this component, I fill it in the other component and that works fine. I've my data on the blade. but for some reason the can't be merges into eachother on the blade, only in the component.

Comment: You simply have not provided enough info to be able to clearly understand what is happening in your component(s) and where the issue lies.